# Single field body in Spring Rest request

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

in Spring, is it possible to eg. `POST` single object to controller with `@RequestBody`?
Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody Long userId) {
    // do smth with userId
}
```

If yes, what should `json` body look like?

Comment: What is content in request body?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As your `@RequestBody` is primitive so you have to send just simple number in body. Following snap of request body using POSTMAN
[image: request body screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible.

This is a curl command that gets back a Http 200 for the above said end point

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/users -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d "123"
```

Data is just a string literal "123"